# Verifications involving non-mocked class with mocked abstract parent

Tags: jmockit

A member of my team has written a JMockit-based test method that using a `Verifications` instance to assert a method was invoked on the UUT, which is not mocked, but extends a mocked abstract parent (it happens to be a Hibernate repository).  The test passes, but my opinion, based on the JMockit documentation, is that only mocks should be used in a `Verifications` instance initializer.  I think the result is a false negative but my team member insists it's a valid verification call.  The test itself is simple, so I've recreated it using contrived objects:

```
package com.acme.dataacess;

public abstract class AbstractRepository {

    public final T list(Class<T> clazz, final Collection<String> keys) {
       .....
    }
}

package com.acme.module.dataacess

public class FooRepository extends AbstractRepository<Foo> {

    public List<Foo> list() {
        return getFoos(null);
    }

    public List<Foo> list(Collection<String> keys) {
        return list(Foo.class, keys);
   }
}

public class FooRepositoryTest {

    @Tested
    private FooRepository uut;

    @Mocked
    private AbstractRepository mockAbstractRepository;

    @Test
    public void testFoo1() {

       // Execute the test.
       this.uut.list(null);

       // Verify the results.
       new Verifications() {
           {
               // I don't think this is a valid verification, because the goal
               // of the test is to assert a delegated method in a non-mocked
               // class was invoked.
               uut.list(null);
           }
       };

    }
}
```

Is this a valid JMockit verification?

Comment: You're right, that verification is completely worthless, it checks nothing. And even if the test was "fixed" by verifying a call to `mockAbstractRepository.list(Foo.class, null)`, it would still be a bad test. A good, useful test would verify that `FooRepository#list(Collection)` actually does what it's supposed to do (ie, to actually find a list of the correct "foos" in the database, having the given keys, and nothing more), not merely that it calls the correct method in the base class. Test for *meaningful behavior*, not for implementation details - and avoid mocking as much as possible.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to answer the question.  Your answer echoes a lot of the same points I've been trying to make to my team.  I also appreciate all the time you've put into JMockit.  It's a great framework that has made my life much easier the last couple of years!